# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una clase a la clase donde alojo mi tabHost?

Tags: android

Muy buenas colegas, tengo un error que no logro resolver, necesito llamar una clase para que se ejecute dentro de la clase en donde llamo a mi tabHost, ya me muestra las pestañas que necesito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo para poder hacer que me muestre eso

```
public class ContenedorInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contenedor_info);

    TabHost tab = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tab.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
    spec1.setIndicator("Concesionarios");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.concesionarios);
    tab.addTab(spec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Solicitudes");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.solicitudes);
    tab.addTab(spec2);
}
```

}

pero ahora no se que tengo que hacer para que ahí en esa clase me ejecute el código de las otras clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el código de una de las clases.

```
public class Concesionarios extends Activity {

public ListView lstEmp;
public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myItemEmp;
public AdapterEmpresas myAdapterEmp;

//DAO EMPRESAS;
public DaoEmpresas myDaoEmp;

//conexion base de datos
private String ip = "192.168.42.49";
private final String URL_SERVICE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/servidor.php#";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/";
private String METHOD_NAME = "";
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;


private SoapObject request;
private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelo;
private HttpTransportSE transport;


private PropertyInfo empresa = null;

ProgressDialog dialogAsynk;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_concesionarios);

    lstEmp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstConcesionarios);
    myItemEmp = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

    myDaoEmp = new DaoEmpresas(getApplication());
    myItemEmp = myDaoEmp.getAllEmpresas();


    myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(this, myItemEmp);
    lstEmp.setAdapter(myAdapterEmp);
    registerForContextMenu(lstEmp);

    new EmpresaEnSegundoPlano().execute("");
}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0, "Actualizar");
    menu.add(0,1,1, "Ver Solicitudes");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            new EmpresaEnSegundoPlano().execute("");
            break;
        case 1:
            //Intent i = new Intent(Concesionarios.this, Solicitudes.class);
            //startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}*/

public void reload(){
    myDaoEmp = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());
    myItemEmp = myDaoEmp.getAllEmpresas();
    myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(this, myItemEmp);
    lstEmp.setAdapter(myAdapterEmp);
}

public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> LanzarEmpresa(String params){
    METHOD_NAME = "getEmpresa";
    SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

    ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myArrayWs = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

    try {
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        empresa = new PropertyInfo();
        empresa.setName("empresa");
        empresa.setValue(params);
        empresa.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(empresa);


        envelo = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelo.dotNet = false;
        envelo.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SERVICE);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelo);

        String resultado = (String) envelo.getResponse();

        Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>() {}.getType();

        Gson convertidoJson = new Gson();

        myArrayWs = convertidoJson.fromJson(resultado, tipo);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myArrayWs;
}

//**********************Tarea asyncrona***********************//
class EmpresaEnSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> doInBackground(String... params) {
        return LanzarEmpresa(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogAsynk = ProgressDialog.show(Concesionarios.this, "", "espera", true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
        super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
        dialogAsynk.dismiss();

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tamaño del arrego: " + itemEmpresases.size());


        DaoEmpresas myDao = new DaoEmpresas(getApplicationContext());

        for (ItemEmpresas empresas : itemEmpresases) {
            if (myDao.insertEmpresa(empresas) == true){
                //Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                //probar aquí una validación para que no se vuelva a repetir el ciclo y
                //re-inserte la informacion que ya esta
                reload();
            }else{
                Crouton.makeText(Concesionarios.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
}
```

ERROR:

```
03-28 20:17:18.250 31531-31531/com.example.sebastian.sigc11appv01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.sebastian.sigc11appv01, PID: 31531
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sebastian.sigc11appv01/com.example.sebastian.sigc11appv01.SIGC11Classes.ContenedorInfo}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
                                                                                    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:754)
                                                                                    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:420)
                                                                                    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:247)
                                                                                    at com.example.sebastian.sigc11appv01.SIGC11Classes.ContenedorInfo.onCreate(ContenedorInfo.java:24)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Vista completa sin iniciar los Intent:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega las Activity creando un Intent:

```
   TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
    spec1.setIndicator("Concesionarios");
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    spec1.setContent(activityIntent);
    tab.addTab(spec1);
```

Tu Activity debe extender de [ActivityGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) :

```
 public class MyActivity extends ActivityGroup {
  ...
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora mismo lo hago

Comment: Creo que no se puede, me manda un error y se detiene la aplicación, pongo el error que muestra el logcat

Comment: Tu Activity debe extender de ActivityGroup.

Comment: Al parecer ya esta obsoleto AtivityGroup, lo que hice pues llamar crear el intente y ejecutarlo fuera de los paracentesis y si me muestra lo que espero que me muestra pero fuera del tabHost, o sea que no toma en cuenta que este junto si no que lo tomo como actividades independientes